# Python multiprocessing: two threads stopping each other

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to move a small motor-powered carriage on a rail. There is an Infrared Detector on the rail in order to prevent the carriage to go too far. The whole system is supervised by a Raspberry Pi 3.

I am trying to set up two processes with the multiprocessing package: the first one is the `move_process` which basically just calls a function that moves the motor for a selected number of steps.

```
def move():
    motor.step(steps, direction, stepmode)
    watch_process.terminate()
```

The second one is the `watch_process` which calls an infinite loop function waiting for the input from the IR detector :

```
def watch()
    while True:
        detector_input = GPIO.input(18)
        if detector_input == False:
            move_process.terminate()
            break
```

I want the `watch_process` to kill the `move_process` if the detector sends an input. I also want the `move_process` to kill the `watch_process` if everything went fine, i.e. when the motor successfully moved without triggering the detector.

I define a function that is fired up when I press a "go" button:

```
def on_go_pressed():
    move_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=move)
    watch_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=watch)
    move_process.start(), watch_process.start()
```

Can you provide a simple solution for those two processes supposed to kill each other?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT: typo

Comment: When you run `motor.step` does it actually sit there and run that function or does the program just keep going?

Comment: @chbchb55 `motor.step` starts the motor and the line after that will be executed only after the motor has finished moving.

Comment: @roganjosh When the detector sends an input the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'` is thrown. And the same error happens when the `move_process` kills the `watch_process`

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if that's due to the way that multiprocessing forks processes (I wouldn't expect `move_process` to mean anything to `watch()` from what you've posted). My personal approach, and this is a guess for sure, would be to use a [`Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to share a state between the processes, and to mave `move()` check the state in the manager regularly.

Comment: @roganjosh Here is the problem: the `move_process` cannot check regularly for some flag or anything like that because it would make the motor stutter. It has to be interrupted from the "outside".

Comment: Genuine question; a millisecond-or-so check will stutter the motor?

Comment: If that's the case, I guess you need to give `watch()` access to the actual process that's spawned from `move_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=move)`. How exactly you do that, I'm not sure, but I'll be watching this question for sure :) In your current setup it can't see it on the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on signals to do so. Under the hood, the `Process.terminate()` method delivers a `SIGTERM` signal to the target process.

You need a Queue or Pipe to sent to the processes each other PID. Only the parent process can do so.

Here's a simple example using two pipes.

```
import os
import signal
import multiprocessing

def watch(pipe)
    move_process_pid = pipe.recv()
    while True: 
       if not GPIO.input(18):
           os.kill(move_process_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
           return

def move(pipe):
    watch_process_pid = pipe.recv()
    motor.step(steps, direction, stepmode)
    os.kill(watch_process_pid, signal.SIGTERM)  

def on_go_pressed():
    move_process_reader, move_process_writer = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
    watch_process_reader, watch_process_writer = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
    move_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=move, args=(move_process_reader,))
    watch_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=watch, args=(watch_process_reader,))

    move_process.start()
    watch_process.start()

    move_process_writer.send(watch_process.pid)
    watch_process_writer.send(move_process.pid)
```